# How can I do web scraping via puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

If I go to `https://investor.vanguard.com/mutual-funds/profile/VMMXX` and execute `document.querySelector("[data-ng-if='productSummaryTitle']").innerText` from console, I get what I am expecting: `Product summary`.

But when I try to do the same with `puppeteer`, I get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:3:83`. What am I missing?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://investor.vanguard.com/mutual-funds/profile/VMMXX')

    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let myText = document.querySelector("[data-ng-if='productSummaryTitle']").innerText
        return {
            myText
        }
    })

    console.log(result)

    browser.close()
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wait for that selector first

```js
const element = await page.waitForSelector('[data-ng-if='productSummaryTitle']');
const text = await element.evaluate(el => el.innerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://investor.vanguard.com/mutual-funds/profile/VMMXX');
const element = await page.waitForSelector("[data-ng-if='productSummaryTitle']");
const text = await element.evaluate(el => el.innerText);
console.log(text);
await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.